# Wrapping legend in r

Tags: r

Is there a way to wrap the legend so that it goes to the new line or column in r? Even tried to reduce the size but din't work.

[Image of my plot-notice legend in overflowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBuuj.png)

```
p <- ggplot(cohort.chart.cl, aes(x=month, y=clients, group=cohort))
p + geom_area(aes(fill = cohort)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = reds(nrow(cohort.clients))) +
  ggtitle('Customer Cohort') + theme(legend.position="bottom",panel.background=element_rect(fill = "light grey"),legend.text = element_text(size = 7),legend.key.size = unit(0.25, "cm"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `guides()` and pick the number of rows of your legend that looks most attractive:

```
p <- ggplot(cohort.chart.cl, aes(x=month, y=clients, group=cohort))
    p + geom_area(aes(fill = cohort)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = reds(nrow(cohort.clients))) +
      ggtitle('Customer Cohort') + theme(legend.position="bottom",panel.background=element_rect(fill = "light grey"),legend.text = element_text(size = 7),legend.key.size = unit(0.25, "cm")) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 3))  # or experiment with other numbers of rows
```